# Clipping raster layer created by Georaster plugin in Leaflet?

Tags: raster, leaflet, geojson, clip, leaflet-plugins

I want to clip a raster layer inside Leaflet. I want it to clip by a GeoJSON.

I couldn't find an effective method to do it. The below code is what I have done so far. Can anyone suggest a method?

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([17.877083, 70.697917], 8);

L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: '&copy; <a 
href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> 
contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var url_to_geotiff_file = "L2_22.tif";

fetch(url_to_geotiff_file)
  .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then(arrayBuffer => {
    parseGeoraster(arrayBuffer).then(georaster => {
      console.log("georaster:", georaster);

      var layer = new GeoRasterLayer({
          georaster: georaster,
          opacity:0.9,
          clip: undifined
      });
      layer.addTo(map);

      map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());

  });
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "clip"? Initially show clipped image? Programmatically clip image later? Interactively clip by drawing? You also write "I have tried many methods". What methods? Please edit your question with additional info.

Comment: Also add info where is `GeoRasterLayer` coming from.

Comment: <script src="https://unpkg.com/georaster"></script>

this is where georaster has come from

Comment: It is enough if initially show the clipped image

Answer (score 0):

You are using [georaster-layer-for-leaflet](https://github.com/geotiff/georaster-layer-for-leaflet) plugin to display GeoTIFF raster image.

If you look at it's advanced capabilities at https://github.com/GeoTIFF/georaster-layer-for-leaflet/blob/master/ADVANCED.md, you'll notice Masking section, where `mask` and `mask_strategy` options are described. These allow you to mask you raster with GeoJSON geometry.

In your case relevant part of the code could look something like this:

```
var clipArea =
  {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [
                142.10447595438035,
                -30.81558549284705
              ],
              [
                142.10447595438035,
                -34.804178162266126
              ],
              [
                149.95464435961424,
                -34.804178162266126
              ],
              [
                149.95464435961424,
                -30.81558549284705
              ],
              [
                142.10447595438035,
                -30.81558549284705
              ]
            ]
          ],
          "type": "Polygon"
        }
      }
    ]
  };

fetch(url_to_geotiff_file)
  .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then(arrayBuffer => {
    parseGeoraster(arrayBuffer).then(georaster => {      
      var layer = new GeoRasterLayer({
        georaster: georaster,
        opacity:0.9,
        mask: clipArea,
        mask_strategy: "outside",
      });
      layer.addTo(map);     
      map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());    
  });
});
```

Here is sample of full GeoTIFF:

[image]

And here is sample of the same GeoTIFF clipped with the above GeoJSON:

[image]